# parallel summation of arrays with openmp in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp

I have a for-loop in C++ that takes a lot of computation time and that I would like to parallelize by using OpenMP (I have 16 cores available). Other, more simple for-loops and FFTs of my code are already parallelized with OpenMP and work fine. I have tried some options but the results were nothing (orders of magnitude difference) like the one computed serially.

My corresponding part of my code looks essentially like the following:

```
for (i1=1;i1<N;i1++){
    function(Nx, Ny, i1, k, vector_1, vector_2);
    for (i=0;i<(Nx*Ny);i++){
        vector_3[i] = I*kx[i/Ny]*vector_2[i];
    }
    for (i=0;i<(Nx*Ny);i++){
        sum[i1-1] -= vector_2[i];
    }

    fftw_execute(p_c2r_4);
    #pragma omp parallel for default(shared)
    for (i=0;i<(Nx*Ny);i++){
        vector_4[i] = vector_4[i]/norm;
    }

    for (i2=1;i2<N;i2++){
    function(Nx, Ny, i2, k, vector_1, vector_2);
        for (i=0;i<(Nx*Ny);i++){
            Trans[(i1-1)*N + (i2-1)] -= creal( vector_2[i]*vector_4[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

One of the for-loops is already parallelized, so my goal is to parallelize the others. For the sums I have seen others using `reduction(+:sum)` but in my case `sum` is an array and I get an error when compiling.

Can someone give me a hint because this is a big bottleneck in my code?

Comment: What are the #pragmas that you put?

Comment: Well, I tried `#pragma omp parallel for default(shared)` at every loop but the result was completely wrong. Then I tried to make some variables private, like `private(i1,k,vector_1,vector_2)` but this was just a desperate try and it didn't work neither.

Comment: Mess around with the schedule clause. If your loop counts are not compiled constants dynamic or guided may work better.

Answer (score 3):

The first for loop should work similarly as the third.

With the sum the slight problem is that the sum[] array is indexed using the first loop index and therefore seems to confuse the compiler. To make it easier for the machine, you can try:

```
double subsum=0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) reduction(+:subsum)
for (i=0;i<(Nx*Ny);i++){
    subsum += vector_2[i];
}
sum[i1-1] -= subsum;
```

With the fourth you can probably use similar trick.

Comment: Is it necessary that the initialization `double subsum=0.0` is done after the `#pragma ...` and before the for-loop?

Comment: Sorry for the syntax error introduced, the variable of course must be declared before used by omp directive. And set to 0 during each outer for loop.